# When do you use SP.js?

Tags: javascript

This might be a very noob question, but when do you actually use SP.js? In my SharePoint site I am using ajax queries with the [REST api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380(v=office.15).aspx) like this:
http://dev.spdev.local/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Random List')/items

Is SP.js just for apps that run in iFrames? Or are people using it on regular SharePoint webpages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sp.js is a JavaScript library which you should use if you want to use SharePoint client object model in JavaScript. See this link for all methods and properties available in the library. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245759(v=office.15).aspx . There is no restrictions like it should be used only in apps or iframe etc.

Comment: When I type new SP.ClientContext() into my browser's console I get back "Object doesn't support this action". Is there some kind of setup involved before using it?

Comment: Follow this link to see basic examples of using sp.js http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: You want to use `var myContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current()` or `var myContext = new SP.ClientContext('yourFullSiteUrl')` if you're trying to access a client context.

Answer (score 2):

This JavaScript object library reference contains information that you can use to build custom sites, farm solutions, and apps for SharePoint. JavaScript in SharePoint 2013 is derived from the .NET server programming model, and the programming capabilities defined here reflect those found in the original .NET server source.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193034(v=office.15).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246996(v=office.15).aspx